# How can i fix This error in background notification handler?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with app flutter when I integrate firebase_messaging to receive notification in the background
when I debug I get this error :

`I/FLTFireBGExecutor(29060): Creating background FlutterEngine instance, with args: [--start-paused, --enable-dart-profiling] W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry(29060): Attempted to register plugin (io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry$ShimRegistrarAggregate@2549a44) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@99e972d). E/MethodChannel#(29060): Parameter messenger must not be null. I/BlockMonitor(29060): dispatchingThrewException In MainThread D/AndroidRuntime(29060): Shutting down VM I/QarthLog(29060): [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile I/QarthLog(29060): [PatchStore] create disable file for com.dgmsolutions.foolivery uid is 10523 E/AndroidRuntime(29060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(29060): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler(java.lang.String, io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger$BinaryMessageHandler)' on a null object reference E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(MethodChannel.java:119) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.initInstance(FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:64) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:58) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at com.dgmsolutions.foolivery.Application.registerWith(Application.kt:16) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor.lambda$null$0$FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor(FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor.java:206) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor$e4cdQ2b1x-adsVcO-hA2dn2VM8E.run(Unknown Source:6) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) E/AndroidRuntime(29060):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101) I/Process (29060): Sending signal. PID: 29060 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device.`

my code (in the picture)
[main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4JEr.png)

[application.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k85xc.png)

[manifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8In61.png)

[notification class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KLao.png)

Comment: What is your Flutter version ? If you are running a version >= 1.12, you don't need to implement the Android configuration as mentioned in the official documenation. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/

Comment: my version Flutter 2.0.1 • channel stable I don t need it configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running Flutter 2.0.1, you only need to configure the Flutter part of the firebase messaging plugin, and add your google-services.json files.
Read carefully the official documentation and you'll fix your problem :)

If you need a sample project showcasing how to implement the Firebase Notifications, you can take a look [at this one](https://github.com/FDuhen/fcm-cleanarch--flutter)